# Translucent with Navigation Bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I customized my navigation bar to clear. So I set the backgroundImage as UIImage() and isTranslucent = true. So the problem I got here is: That is what I set in my xib. Now TopConstraints is: 10px [image]
With topConstraint = 10. When I run in simulator iPhone 5s: this is what i got. The screen is perfect. Although I remember that, if I set isTranslucent = true -> I must set topConstraint is higher more than navigation bar height, ex: topConstraint = 50.[image]. But with this code, when I tried to run in real device: iPhone 5s. and this is what I got: [image]
The navigation bar is cover the view. My simulator is run in iOS 11.0, and real device is run in iOS 9.2. Anyone have the same situation? Thanks so much

BTW: I need to set my navigation bar is clear because our background color is gradient color from top-left to bottom-right

Answer (score 2):

Remove backgroundImage as UIImage() and try this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

And keep the topConstraint = 10